# XCode Storyboard and UIViewController instantiation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Good afternoon,

I have a storyboard configured but I have difficulty with one aspect.

I am using a UITableView to recreate a directory structure i.e. folder>subfolder>files. The structure is going to be different for every user and the structure is supplied via a API. I currently have a UITableViewController within the storyboard.

How can I recreate this in the storyboard?

Currently I am just recreating another instance of the UITableViewController class and pushing it on to the UINavigationController but I of course lose all of the assigned segues.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using segues for each cell? If so, you should be using identifiers for each cell then you can call and place each cell according to the data structure coming in. Then in your didSelectRowAtIndex you can segue to different views or pass different data.

Comment: It's not clear from this description what it is you are trying to do.  Do you have any pictures or examples of what it is you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect one scene to represent the folder hierarchy. It would be a single UITableViewController with a table with 2 prototype table view cells. One table view cell would be for folders, the other for files. The table cell for the folders would have a push segue leading back in a loop to the table view controller. The file segue would lead to what ever scene you uses for files.

You can to use the table view data source and delegate methods to drive the table view and fill it with instances of your prototype cells.